# How i can open *.ps.gz file on mac

Tags: macos, gzip

I tried to open the

```
*.ps.gz
```

file through the finder i double clicked on the file, then i got a

```
*.ps.gz.cpgz
```

file, then i double clicked on the

```
*.ps.gz.cpgz
```

file and i got the first file

```
*.ps.gz
```

it seems that i struggle in the loop, how i can open it?

Comment: have you tried unpacking it in the terminal? `gz` signifies that it was packed with `gzip`, the unpacker program is called `gunzip` and should be available in the command line.

You will then get a .ps ([postscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript)) file.